# Cannot import parse tfrecords serialized examples

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I am trying to save some index and float values to **tfrecords** and parse them using the **tf.data** api.

I am using **tensorflow2.1** version **2.1.0rc1**
On Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.7.5

First I create the example:

```py
def create_example(row_ix, col_ix, cooc_val):
    return tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={
                "rows": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[row_ix])),
                "cols": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[col_ix])),
                "cooc": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[cooc_val]))
            }
        )
    )
```

The method to save to a **tfrecord**

```py
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter("train.tfrecord") as writer:
    for row_ix, col_ix, cooc_val in tqdm(zip(glove_rows, glove_cols, glove_data)):
        example = create_example(row_ix, col_ix, cooc_val)
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Now, I open the **tfrecord** file using the **tf.data** api:

```py
train_ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(os.path.join(data_path, "train.tfrecord"))
```

And then, I parse the example

```py
feature_description = {
    "rows": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=0),
    "cols": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=0),
    "cooc": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, default_value=0.0)
}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

train_ds = train_ds.map(_parse_function)
```

which returns the following error:

```sh
InvalidArgumentError: Could not parse example input, value: '
cols
C
rows


cooc
IA'
     [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]
```

Comment: I tried reproducing the error in this notebook, but I don't get any errors: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H86a4vYHoM0TPT3O3f72N1QFBsQq_c2o. Can you share full repro instructions?

Comment: @AAudibert it is edited. I used tf2.1

Comment: Can you include the code to generate the input data? When I generate dummy data using `tf.ones`, this code works fine with Python 3.7.5 and TensorFlow 2.1.0-rc1